# Does WKC have its own version, or is it just CP4D's version?

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

I can't find a WKC specific version in the IBM docs. Does WKC have its own versioning, or is it just (lite/full) version for a specific version of Cloud Pak 4 Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of services are related to the version of CPD.  Under the covers, the service is a collection of microservices which are versioned.  But that should be transparent to end users.